# ASP.NET MVC cookies are not included in the response headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I'm trying to set a cookie. (Specifically, it's being done by a custom SessionIDManager.)

When I debug the code where the cookie gets set, it gets called as expected. When I look at the context after the controller action finishes, the cookie is in the response CookieCollection.

However, Fiddler & the browser show that the actual cookie is *sometimes* missing from the HTTP response headers.

It's consistent on a per-action basis; that is, some controllers/actions are fine, and others aren't, and it's always consistent as far as I can tell.

I don't see anything to distinguish the actions that succeed and those that don't - no difference in the attributes/filters/return type. (So it's not like the broken ones are trying to do Response.Redirect, etc.)

It's not a problem with the cookie setting code (trying to set it in the request instead of the response, etc.), or else it would *never* work. Does anybody have any suggestions for where else I could look to explain what's going on?

EDIT: While I can't recreate the *success*, I've recreated the *failure* in a new solution, which can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0p1ffvzxs0wmjp/RecreateCookieIssues.zip?dl=0). My SessionIDManager gets called, I see the cookie in the response in the controller when I peek with the debug tools, but it doesn't actually make it into the HTTP response.

Comment: It would help to see the relevant sections of your startup.cs - to see what middleware you have configured.

Comment: This is MVC 5, so there's no Startup.cs (that's an ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 concept).

The only filters I have are an AuthenticationAttribute and an AuthorizationAttribute. They all get run before the action - and they're consistent across all the actions...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question as 6. Do you have any other IHttpModules installed that could be changing the outbound response?

Comment: Nothing set up in Web.config. I'm running this locally in IIS Express, so I don't think there's any "system-wide" modules that that sets up, but if I'm wrong I'd love to be educated.

I created the symptoms in a new solution, and have added a link to that to the OP.